# Why my reputation go down suddenly? Serial upvoting reversed

Tags: discussion, support

Many times my reputation is decreased

I found writing:  Serial upvoting reversed

What does it mean?! what the wrong i did.

This issue repeated 3 times till now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means a user has been upvoting you many times in a row, and it appears that they are unfairly trying to give you reputation. You can ask a moderator in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) to ask the user to stop.

With that said, you are not in any fault *unless you controlled the account that upvoted you serially, or asked for those upvotes(solicited them)*. If you have done so, please just stop now, as no bad action has been taken against you yet.

Comment: I didn't control another account that upvoted for me and also i didn't ask anybody unless they told me that my answer solved their problem.So, it is not my fault if some user is upvoting to me!!! in this manner i can start upvoting to somebody to make his reputation down!!! how could that be!!! it's unfair

Comment: You do not lower someone's reputation. Let's say I am a user at 1000 rep, and you upvote me 10 times. I am now at 1100 rep, and when the serial upvoting is reversed,I am back at 1000 rep. I never lose rep, I just end up never gaining it. The reason the rep goes up when the user votes but down later is that the system to check for serial voting runs only every so often, 24 hours, IIRC.