# I am being downvoted for no reason

Tags: discussion, downvoting

[image]

Can a moderator explain what's happening to my account. I am not sad but I wish to know why I am so downvoted today?

### EDIT:

Problem solved next 2 days
I have my points back

[image]

Comment: Man you have got yourself a stalker.That looks like some serious grudge

Comment: Looks like serial downvoting. If it is, it should be automatically reversed in a day - and I assume the perpetrator will be given a warning, in private.

Comment: @kamil did you have any doubt about someone, look at their profiles.It shows everything.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Users' profiles do *not* show votes. You may be thinking that downvotes would appear as reputation losses in the reputation history. But they do not: you can only see that information in your own profile.

Comment: I have encounter a serial upvote (gained something like 170 rep in 15min), but everything was reversed a few hours later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why my reputation go down suddenly? Serial upvoting reversed](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4146/why-my-reputation-go-down-suddenly-serial-upvoting-reversed)

Comment: @Braiam This is a bit different, as it's serial downvoting not upvoting (and a different answer applies).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've looked into this and have determined the culprits.

This will be dealt with overnight by the serial voting reversal mechanism - so just hang-on tight.

As to the culprits - they will be suitably dealt with once the votes have been invalidated.

Comment: @fossfreedom I have the same issue...

Comment: @Jobin I am sure his account is Just right now suspended because of what he did. I don't mean to name it without proof. But what a coincidence!

Comment: @Hadi i didn't see any serial downvoting on your's.

Comment: @fossfreedom I am still under attack although raju is suspended!

Comment: @Hadi somebody upvoted you serially upto 1225 reputations.How?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes that happened before and I was suspended unfairly. It's not my problem with that users who make such thing must be forbidden forever

Comment: @Kamil - dont worry about it - it will sort itself out overnight.

Comment: @fossfreedom Thanks for clarification But Is it important to suspended the user originating this or simply reverse downvotes?

Comment: @kamil - suspensions are private between the parties and I will not go into the details here as to what reasons a person has been suspended.

Comment: @fossfreedom Ok I am sorry for that

Comment: @fossfreedom nicely handled.